# Change font awesome icon when bootstrap dropdown is clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a font awesome icon in the title of a bootstrap dropdown. When I click on the dropdown, the background color changes to green and the text color becomes a darker shade of grey. My problem is, that the fa-icon doesn't change the color too and because it has the same tone of green, it becomes "invisible". How can I change the color of both the link and the fa-icon when the dropdown is pressed? 
The link to the site with the problem is: www.jojogames.de/TwoScopes/index.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code here?

Comment: Post the code if you want more help.

Comment: I've tried many things myself so I wasn't sure what code would be relevant, hence why I didn't post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color of `.faicon` on hover, target the parent `.dropdown:hover` with `.faicon` as a child. As for the invisible icon, target the dropdown when its opened with `.dropdown.open`. Of course, red and purple are placeholder colors and would be replaced.

```
<li class="dropdown><a href="#">Team <i class="fa fa-users faicon"></i></a></li>
```

CSS

```
.faicon {
  color: #30D31C;
}
.dropdown:hover .faicon,
.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle:hover .faicon {
  color: red;
}
.dropdown.open .faicon {
  color: purple;
}
```